# how to input into string array in c++

Tags: c++

i want to declare an array of strings and want to input string via CIN command but it gives me an error 
i am trying to do this 
name1
name2 
name3
.
.
. and so on...
i am entering string to an array dynamical means input from cin

for CIN i use the following code 
like if i use 3 names to be entered

```
string arr[3];  
for (int x=0;x<3;x++)
{
cout<<"enter name"<<x<<" ";
cin<<arr[x];
}
for(int z=0;z<3;z++)
cout<<arr[z];
```

it gives an error NO MATCH FOR CIN....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<<` is for output.  Use `cin >> arr[x];` for input.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `cin >> arr[x];` instead of `cin<<arr[x];`