# Char array takes only a part of the string

Tags: c++

Disclaimer: I have to use char arrays instead of strings because this is a part of my home assignment.

I try to input a string from a keyboard into a char array. However, it always inputs only the first word, independently of how I declare the array. Two examples of when I do this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char arr[] = "";
    std::cin >> arr;
    return 0; 
}
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char* arr = new char[100];
    std::cin >> arr;
    return 0;
}
```

Both times I expect the string I enter to be stored in *arr* fully, but it stores only the first word: all the symbols before the first space.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19898510/8708630) post.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks, this solves it!

Comment: You need to make sure your array is large enough. In your first example it only has space for one character. Which for a null-terminated string would be the null terminator.

Comment: @juanchopanza No, it expands automatically, it seems--when I run the first example, it stores the first word no matter how many characters are there. The problem is in that I need to use getline(), as I was kindly informed in the first comment.

Comment: No, arrays don't expand automatically. What happens is C++ allows you to go out of bounds. If you go far enough you may even get a seg fault.

Comment: All right, I'll remember that.

Comment: your code doesn't even compile

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Fixed now (hopefully). It's not a part of my actual code, I just wrote these examples from memory and forgot a couple of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use `std::cin.getline()` it will assume next variable to enter after a space.